# GoLang CGO file handles

Tags: go, cgo

I’m working with a native linux C binary which has a fairly expensive initialization call which I would like to perform once at application startup. This call should open a bunch of file handles internally for later use. When I call this expensive initialization C function from Go, it completes successfully and correctly opens the files but those handles are open only for the duration of the call to the C function! This means that when I call successive C functions against the same library from Go, the file handles are no longer open and the calls fail. I have verified this using the lsof command. Interestingly, when the initialization call as well as calls to subsequent behavior are composed into a single C function which is then called from Go, the files are opened and remain open, allowing successful completion of all desired functionality.

Is there some kind of undocumented cgo behavior which is “cleaning up”, shutting down, or even leaking file handles or other stateful resources between multiple invocations of C functions from Go? If so, is this behavior configurable? We don’t have access to the source code for this library.

Also, I've verified that this is not related to thread-local storage. Calling `runtime.LockOSThread()` has no effect and we've verified that the files are closed after control returns from C back to the calling Go code.

Here’s an example of the kind of Go code I’d like to write:

```
// Go code:

func main() {
    C.Initialize()
    C.do_stuff() // internal state is already cleaned up! This call fails as a result. :(
}
```

Here’s an example of a C function that invokes the initialization and behavior all at once. This “wrapping” function is invoked from Go:

```
// C code:

void DoEverything(void)
{
    Initialize();
    do_stuff(); // succeeds because all internal state is intact (not cleaned up).
}
```

Comment: Can you supply a running example that reproduces this behaviour? Which go version do you use?

Comment: Go versions are 1.3 and 1.2. I'll see if I can put together an example that shows the behavior...

Comment: I've written a trivial example that I thought would reproduce the behavior but it worked without exhibiting the bad behavior. I suspect that there's something strange about this C library. Not sure...

Comment: Ok, this is a bit embarrassing, but I figured it out. Right after calling initialize(), I was calling defer close(), but it was actually defer fmt.Println(close()). Because arguments to deferred functions are resolved immediately (not deferred), the close function was being invoked before we could invoke any other behavior. The golang blog clearly explain argument resolution to deferred function calls: http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

Comment: Haha :) Glad you found it. You can answer and accept your own question and mark it as resolved in that way.

Comment: @mdwhatcott, I would also refer to [the relevant bit of the specification](http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) as it specifies the behaviour rather strictly, just the language is a bit dry ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit embarrassing, but I figured it out. Right after calling initialize(), I was calling defer close(), but it was actually defer fmt.Println(close()). Because arguments to deferred functions are resolved immediately (not deferred), the close function was being invoked before we could invoke any other behavior. The golang blog [clearly explains argument resolution to deferred function calls](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).